# this.getClass().getClassLoader() and ClassLoader

Tags: java, classloader

What's the difference between this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource() and ClassLoader#getResource() ?

Frank

Answer (score 2):

The first is the actual code, the second is just a [pointer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) which class/method you should use.

By the way, you should rather have asked this minor question/request-for-clarification in a comment on my answer in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353057/how-to-convert-inputstream-to-fileinputstream).

Answer (score 1):

You mean difference between "**Class**#getResource()" and "**ClassLoader**#getResource()"? If you look at JVM srcs (recommended), you will see that the first is a convenience wrapper method around the latter:

```
public java.net.URL getResource(String name) {
    name = resolveName(name);
    ClassLoader cl = getClassLoader0();
    if (cl==null) {
        // A system class.
        return ClassLoader.getSystemResource(name);
    }
    return cl.getResource(name);
}
```