# Convert InputStream into FileInputStream

Tags: java, iostream

I have read this post [How to convert InputStream to FileInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353057/how-to-convert-inputstream-to-fileinputstream) on converting a InputStream into a FileInputStream. However, the answer does not work if you are using a resource that is in a jar file. Is there another way to do it.

I need to do this to get the `FileChannel` from a call to 
`Object.class.getResourceAsStream(resourceName);`

Comment: Why do you need it? In general, there may not be such an object.

Comment: OK, I'll bite: why do you need the FileChannel ?

Comment: There is a copy function that I am trying to use.

Comment: Note that addition to FileChannel.transferTo() -- which requires the source to be a FileChannel -- there is also FileChannel.transferFrom(), which requires the destination to be so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't, without basically writing to a file. Unless there's a file, there can't be a `FileInputStream` or a `FileChannel`. If at all possible, make sure your code is agnostic to the input source - design it in terms of `InputStream` and `ByteChannel` (or whatever kind of channel is most appropriate).

Answer (score 6):

From the InputStream returned by Class.getResourceAsStream(), you can make a Channel with [Channels.newChannel( InputStream ).](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channels.html#newChannel%28java.io.InputStream%29)

This is not the FileChannel you requested, but it is still a Channel. Is it sufficient to meet your needs?

Comment: Interesting, let me try this out

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a file and you know that the resource is not inside a jar or loaded remotely, then you can use `getResource` instead.

```
URL resourceLocation = Object.class.getResource(resourcePath);
if (resourceLocation == null) { throw new FileNotFoundException(resourcePath); }
File myFile = new File(resourceLocation.toURI());
```

If you don't absolutely need a `FileChannel` or can't make assumptions about how your classpath is laid out, then Andy Thomas-Cramer's solution is probably the best.

Comment: Thanks Mike, but the resource I need will be inside a JAR file.

Comment: In that case, you can't do it without mounting the jar as a file system somehow.  A file channel presupposes a file.  cheers