# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp$2 cannot be cast to java.io.FileInputStream

Tags: java

I'm downloading a file from remote server using sftp channel as inputstream and trying to cast into fileinputstream. Then I'm receiving following exception from jvm 1.8

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp$2 cannot be cast to java.io.FileInputStream

Please someone help. I'm stuck here

Comment: You need to show the relevant part of your code. Anyway: you try to cast something into something that it cannot be cast into because the types are not related to each other.

Comment: Whatever the `Channel.getInputStream()` method returns, it is never a `FileInputStream`. `FileInputStream`s are only created if you open a local file for reading.

Comment: Thanks for that Thomas, but what I can't understand is the exception argument must be classcast exception input stream can't be converted to fileinputstream but instead it is returning.                                              java.lang.ClassCastException: com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp$2 cannot be cast to java.io.FileInputStream

Comment: That exception message only means that `Channel.getInputStream()` creates and returns an anonymous subclass of `InputStream` which is identified by `com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp$2`. The class is defined and instantiated at https://github.com/rtyley/jsch/blob/master/src/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.java#L1044

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I've got what I'm expecting for. Thanks for sharing the git link

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert from input stream to a FileInputStream without creating a temporal File. See: [Convert InputStream into FileInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355040/convert-inputstream-into-fileinputstream)

If you want to read a file from remote and then write into a file:

```
Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
channel.connect();
ChannelSftp channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
try {
    InputStream inputStream = channelSftp.get(srcPath);
    File file = //...
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
    outputStream.close();
} finally {
    channel.disconnect();
    session.disconnect();
}
```

You can delete it after as in this response:
[How to convert InputStream to virtual File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317035/how-to-convert-inputstream-to-virtual-file)